# Is there a side effect if we use listings.sty with  chained styles?

Tags: listings

Even though I have not detected the side effect, I am still worrying I might do a bad practice here.

Is there a hidden side effect when doing the following?

```
\documentclass[cmyk]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinestyle{Common}
{       
    language={[LaTeX]TeX},
    linewidth=0.5\linewidth%
}


\lstdefinestyle{A}
{
    style=Common,
  backgroundcolor=\color{yellow!50}%      
}

\lstdefinestyle{B}
{
    style=Common,
  backgroundcolor=\color{green!50}%   
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=A]
This is \fbox{style A}.
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=B]
This is \fbox{style B}.
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use keywords several times in one definition, the last one in the series is only valid. However, I do not think that your way is a good practice ...

Comment: Why do you think it is not a good practice? My book explains LaTeX, PSTricks, and C#. They use some common attributes so I put the common attributes into a single style called `Common`. Each also has a set of unique attributes, so I define a separate style for it.

Comment: @xport: I meant that it is a better practice to define new styles without using the keyword style itself in this new definition. But this is apersonal decision, no more no less

Comment: OK. Thanks. If there is no bad effect, I will insist on using it. :-)